# How to store keywords for an article

Tags: solr

In SOLR, I have a document that has `id, words (indexed), raw_text` fields. I want to search just `words` field this way:
Words are infinitives of an article (or say keywords).  For parsing and lemmatization(stemming) I use another tool, so that's not the point of the question.

E.g.: for these two articles(texts) words would be:

**1** Yesterday I didn't go to work, because it was holiday.

words: yesterday go work because holiday

**2** Tommorrow I am going to work in the morning and in the evening I am going shopping.

words: tommorrow go work morning evening go shop

**3**   words: go tommorrow work

In a search for "go " I want to have **2** retreived first (be more relevant) because of having more "go"-s than **1**. Also I want to use longer queries with a bunch of words and have retrieved articles containig most of them most times.

E.g: search for: "go tommorrow work"  would return **2** more relevant than **3** because there are two "go"-s contrary to only one in **3**

So the **question**: how should I store `words`? multiValued or just single ? What field type should be used?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Single-valued) `text` would suit you.

The text comes with tokenization, stemming and stop word analyzers.

---

Stemming uses heuristics to derive the root of a word. Among other things, it would find the root of your articles even in infinitive form :-)

[Trying it out](http://qaa.ath.cx/porter_js_demo.html) for your samples (with a few additions):

```
Original: Yesterday [yesterday's] I didn't go to work [working, workable], because it was holiday [holidays].
Stemmed: Yesterdai yesterdai s I didn t go to work work workabl becaus it wa holidai holidai
Original: Tommorrow I am going [go,going,gone] to work in the morning [mornings] and in the evening I am going shopping [shoppers, shops].
Stemmed: Tommorrow I am go go go gone to work in the morn morn and in the even I am go shop shopper shop
```

Because it uses heuristics, "workable" does not share roots with "work" and "gone" doesnt share roots with "go". But its a tradeoff that works much simpler and faster while **not diminishing the result quality**.

---

And "didnt" and "I" are stop words [according to this list](http://www.ranks.nl/resources/stopwords.html), so they are automatically eliminated.

---

If you ever observe unacceptable results too often, take the trouble to implement [Wordnet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu). They [have](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/wngloss.7WN.html) lemma, part of speech and other natural language goodies.

Comment: oh, I didn't mention that I'm using another tool for NLP. I am just interested in the way to store the words (field type...) Thanks